# Laravel 5 form request rules

Tags: validation, request, laravel-5

Is there a way in my form request rules function where I can detect if it is a delete method? Because then there should not be the same rules as if it is a patch method?

Example:

```
public function rules()
{
   if($method!='delete')
   {
        return [
           'title'=>'required',
        ];
   }
}
```

Thanks,
Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `request` method:

```
public function rules()
{
   if(request()->isMethod('delete'))
   {
        return [
           'title'=>'required',
        ];
   }
}
```